# Запись/Чтение таблицы в DataGridView. Сериализация в C#

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

**Добрый день!**

Передо мной стоит следующая задача - организовать запись данных в XML элемента DatagridView, а после чтение туда же  из этого же файлика.

Запись в XML:

```
    XmlTextWriter writer = null;
    writer = new XmlTextWriter("TaskList.xml", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.WriteStartDocument();

    writer.WriteStartElement("TasksTable");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Type", "XML0.1");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.0.0.0");

    //Запись данных
    writer.WriteStartElement("TaskList");
    for (int i = 0; i < TasksTable.RowCount ; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Row");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", TasksTable.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("TaskIsDone", TasksTable.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("TaskIsOutOfDateDate", TasksTable.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("TaskCreated", TasksTable.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Executor", TasksTable.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("TaskName", TasksTable.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("TaskText", TasksTable.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("TaskDoneDate", TasksTable.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();

    writer.Close();
```

Тут все логично и понятно.

**В результате получаю файл:**

```
<TasksTable Type="XML0.1" Version="1.0.0.0">
<TaskList>
<Row ID="1" TaskIsDone="False" TaskIsOutOfDateDate="True" TaskCreated="06.11.2012 21:57:02" Executor="1" TaskName="1" TaskText="" TaskDoneDate="06.11.2012 21:57:02"/>
<Row ID="2" TaskIsDone="False" TaskIsOutOfDateDate="True" TaskCreated="06.11.2012 21:57:06" Executor="2" TaskName="2" TaskText="" TaskDoneDate="06.11.2012 21:57:06"/>
<Row ID="3" TaskIsDone="False" TaskIsOutOfDateDate="True" TaskCreated="06.11.2012 21:57:09" Executor="3" TaskName="3" TaskText="" TaskDoneDate="06.11.2012 21:57:09"/>
</TaskList>
</TasksTable>
```

(плохо видно, но тут три строчки, как и было три строчки в эл. управления).

Проблема в чтении из этого файла. Определяем кол-во строк какое должно быть без проблем, но сами значения не читаются.

XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("TaskList.xml");
            reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;

```
        reader.ReadStartElement();

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.LineNumber; i++)
        {
            TasksTable.Rows.Add();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader.Value); //пустые значения, но кол-во сообщений равно кол-ву колонок
            }
        }
```

Мне раньше не приходилось сериализовать сложные объекты типа DataGridView, а сам я вообще 1Сник) 
**Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться?**
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы что используете в качестве источника данных для грида? `DataTable`? У него есть готовые методы `WriteXml` и `ReadXml`. Если Вы используете типизированный список - используйте класс `XmlSerializer`.

Ваш код говорит о том, что Вы не понимаете идеологию работы дотнетовских гридов. Они работают с теми данными, с которыми связаны, а API для доступа к отображаемым элементам (строкам и колонкам) предназначен для изменения их отображения, а не работы с данными. Для чтения и сохранения данных нужно работать с источником.

Comment: Я делаю расчет на то, что пользователь работает с элементом DataGridView на форме, и данные хранятся в XML-файле. Есди бы я хранил данные в БД, то делал бы через DataSet, Тут же я не вижу как его прицепить(
а на счет идеологии - Вы правы, путаюсь.
Я нашел неплохую статейку по сериализации, откуда и попытался взять кусочек кода для осмысления (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/1af7xa52(v=vs.90).aspx#Y2040)
Начну с идеологии...

Comment: Создайте `DataTable` нужной структуры, присвойте его свойству грида `DataSource` и все манипуляции с данными делайте через `DataTable`. Всё!